# All links have transition time together when the page loads. Why?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-transitions

I am having an issue. As you will see from the code below, I added a transition time to my menu items, so when (on desktop) I hover over them they scale smoothly. That's good, but I noticed that when I click or touch on any text or button that has a link, the transition takes action on all anchor tags. When the page loads, every item that is a link, smoothly "blinks".

What did I do wrong? Should I give every link a different class and add the transition to each class indipendently? Or how?

2. Also, in order to have all the menu link area clickable, I had to add display block not only on the menu container, but also on each link too, ass you can see in the css code (class menuitem). Is that normal or did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much!

I don't think you will be able to see it from the code snippet below, so here is the website hosted on netlify so you can see the transition in action. [my website](https://amicidizampa.netlify.app)

```css
.menu {
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 59px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgb(255,190,139), rgb(255,210,179));
}

.menuitem {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 43px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.item {
  transition: 0.2s;
}


.menuitem:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.item:active {
  transform: scale(.8);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.current {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item home"><a class="current menuitem menuitemactive" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item cani"><a href="cani.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Cani</a></li>
        <li class="item gatti"> <a href="gatti.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Gatti</a></li>
        <li class="item comeaiutarci"><a href="comeaiutarci.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Come aiutarci</a></li>
        <li class="item contatti"><a href="contatti.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Contatti</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The website link doesn't work

Comment: sorry, I uploaded a new version and I must have changed the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand how [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) works.

```
div {
    transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
}
```

In your example, you are transitioning EVERY type of property by not specifying one, as the default property is "all". Best practise is to only transition one property, otherwise every property in the selected element will be transitioned.

Secondly, you should specify which selectors (classes, ID's etc) you wish to transition, so that not all links are affected.

So, if you wanted to just target your menu, and fade the color or text-shadow for example, you would do:

```
.menuitem {
    transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: text-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

If you're using this class any where else on the site (other than the main menu), those links will also be transitioned too.